# Ошибка при добавлении в БД

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

```
public static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int DATEBASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATEBASE_NAME = "ContactDB";
public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contact";

public static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
public static final String KEY_LOGIN = "Login";
public static final String KEY_PASS = "Pass";
public static int countUser = 0;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATEBASE_NAME, null, DATEBASE_VERSION);
}

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT + " ( "
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PASS + " TEXT);";


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);

    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    value.put(KEY_LOGIN, contact.getLogin());
    value.put(KEY_PASS, contact.getPass());

    Long id = db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, value);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "user inserted" + id);
    countUser++;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Contact has no column named Name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Login=fediafedia@ Name=fedia Pass=ihgldihgld
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Contact has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Contact(Login,Name,Pass) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы создали таблицу, а потом в коде добавили еще какие-то поля, но не изменили версию базы данных.

Попробуйте повысить версию `DATEBASE_VERSION` – в этом случае, при подключении к базе данных, будет вызван метод `onUpgrade(...)`, который удалит старую таблицу и создаст новую (при этом **данные**, хранящиеся в таблице **будут потеряны**).

Answer (score 0):

Как версия, скорее всего SQLite ругается на имя поля **Name**. В руководстве SQLite сказано следующее:

> For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined object.

Ну то есть в качестве наименование ваших объектов/сущностей лучше не использовать вообще любые английские слова.

Я бы переименовал:

```
public static final String KEY_NAME = "field_name";
```

Ну и заодно, чтобы 2 раза не вставать в Android по умолчанию ключевое поле должно называться **_ID** (с лидирующим символом подчеркивания)